# filezilla : 425 Can't open data connection

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I've setup a ftp connection with filezilla client

[image]

The transfert mode is default. I've tried with passive and active mode too but regardless of the mode, the result is the same

[image]

Once setup, I'm clicking to connect.

First time, I have this screen with the certificate as expirate

[image]

I click ok and then I have the logs

```
Statut :    Connexion à A.B.C.D:21...
Statut :    Connexion établie, attente du message d'accueil...
Statut :    Initialisation de TLS...
Statut :    Vérification du certificat...
Statut :    Connexion TLS établie.
Statut :    Connecté
Statut :    Récupération du contenu du dossier...
Commande :  PWD
Réponse :   257 "/" is current directory.
Commande :  TYPE I
Réponse :   200 Type set to I
Commande :  PASV
Réponse :   227 Entering Passive Mode (A,B,C,D,158,240)
Commande :  MLSD
Réponse :   425 Can't open data connection.
Erreur :    Cannot retrieve the contents of the folders
```

After the first try and on the remaining attempts, the log is always saying that it cannot connect

```
Réponse :   425 Can't open data connection.
Erreur :    Cannot retrieve the contents of the folders
```

It must be a configuration issue but I'm not sure where lies the issue

Any tips are more than welcomed

**update**

Please find the detailed logs below

```
Statut :    Connexion à A.B.C.D:21...
Statut :    Connexion établie, attente du message d'accueil...
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
Réponse :   220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Commande :  AUTH TLS
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   234 Using authentication type TLS
Statut :    Initialisation de TLS...
Suivi : CTlsSocket::Handshake()
Suivi : CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Suivi : CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Suivi : CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Suivi : CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Suivi : TLS Handshake successful
Suivi : Protocol: TLS1.0, Key exchange: RSA, Cipher: AES-256-CBC, MAC: SHA1
Statut :    Vérification du certificat...
Statut :    Connexion TLS établie.
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Commande :  USER xXx
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   331 Password required for germany
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Commande :  PASS ********
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   230 Logged on
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Commande :  PBSZ 0
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   200 PBSZ=0
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Commande :  PROT P
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   200 Protection level set to P
Statut :    Connecté
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Suivi : Measured latency of 47 ms
Statut :    Récupération du contenu du dossier...
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ChangeDirSend()
Commande :  PWD
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   257 "/" is current directory.
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
Commande :  TYPE I
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   200 Type set to I
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
Commande :  PORT A1,B1,C1,D1,195,172
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   200 Port command successful
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
Commande :  MLSD
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   150 Opening data channel for directory list.
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Réponse :   425 Can't open data connection.
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(2)
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Erreur :    Impossible de récupérer le contenu du dossier
Statut :    Déconnecté du serveur
Suivi : CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Suivi : CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
```

Comment: Activate detailed logging in FileZilla (right-click log pane). The expired certificate isn’t normal, but it’s also not necessarily dangerous. You should encourage the FTP operator to either remove or renew the certificate.

Comment: hi @DanielB thanks for your comment. Please find the detailed log on the updated version of my question

Comment: Hm, that’s not particularly helpful. Also, the detailed log is an attempt using active FTP. That being said, is the IP address in the `PASV` response the server’s IP address you use to connect (or what the domain resolves to) or a private address?

Comment: regarding the 'issue' (if it can be called an issue) with the certificate, I've used winscp and the message with the certificate is not appearing

Comment: @DanielB where is the passive mode in my logs? Is that one? `A1,B1,C1,D1,195,172`

Comment: The `PORT` command is only sent in active mode. In passive mode, the `PASV` command takes its place.

Comment: @DanielB checked the log and indeed in the `PASV` response IP address is the same as the IP address I'm trying to log in