# FileZilla Server refusing connection - 425 error

Tags: firewall, ftp, filezilla, ftps

I've looked at some other questions (for example, [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1138384/809336)) but haven't found an answer there. Here's the issue:

I'm running FileZilla Server (0.9.60) on a server on our network. We have an external server trying to connect by FTPS. The connection has been working for several years, until a week ago. Now the server can connect and log in, but can't put the file. Here's a sample of what the log says:

```
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:01 AM - (not logged in) (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> Connected on port 990, sending welcome message...
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:01 AM - (not logged in) (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:01 AM - (not logged in) (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 220 You have connected to the RAI FTP server.
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - (not logged in) (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> TLS connection established
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - (not logged in) (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> USER USERNAME
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - (not logged in) (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 331 Password required for USERNAME
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - (not logged in) (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> PASS *******
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 230 Logged on
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> SYST
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> CWD /staging/
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 250 CWD successful. "/staging" is current directory.
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> TYPE A
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 200 Type set to A
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> PBSZ 0
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 200 PBSZ=0
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> PROT P
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 200 Protection level set to P
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> PASV
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,26,129)
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> STOR search_report_11012017.txt
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:12 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/staging/search_report_11012017.txt"
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:32 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> TYPE A
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:32 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 200 Type set to A
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:32 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> PASV
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:32 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,24,88)
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:32 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> STOR RAD_Affil_DL_110217.txt
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:30:42 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/staging/RAD_Affil_DL_110217.txt"
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:31:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> QUIT
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:31:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> 221 Goodbye
(000080) 11/2/2017 3:31:02 AM - USERNAME (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)> disconnected
```

Here are the passive mode settings:

[image: settings page for passive FTP]

Windows firewall is on and specifically allowing TCP ports 20,21,990,6000-7000. My sysadmin assures me that the same ports are forwarded through the corporate firewall. I'm not aware of any changes to the server or the firewall in the last week or more. The external server admin isn't aware of any changes on his side either.

Let me know what other information would be helpful.

Comment: So if all ports are properly dealt with, the next question would be: is the external IP address still correct?

Comment: @DanielB Yes - per the log extract above, the external user can connect and log in. They just can't transfer files.

Comment: That log doesn't indicate in any way that the configured "external server IP address" is correct. This setting is only used with data connections, and those fail.

Comment: you need to verify if you get any incoming connection from the target ip. please use wirshark to track this. if possible on both sides. use filter "ip.addr == XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX"

Comment: @harry Once they changed the external FTP client everything was good. No reboots, restart or services, or anything similar that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your sysadmin is wrong.

My understanding of the 227 messages in the log is that the client tried to open the mentioned IP address, first port 6785 (26*256+129),
then 6232 (24*256+88), but both attempts failed.

The connection attempts probably failed because they were blocked,
most likely in the router.
Or maybe the router did not correctly forward these ports to the
computer where resides the FileZilla Server.
It might be safer to give that computer internally a static IP address.

For more info see the FileZilla wiki :
[Setting up your Router to Fix the "425 code"](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Setting_up_your_Router_to_Fix_the_%22425_code%22#Device_Specific_Instructions).

Comment: So the problem never actually got solved, but the other side changed FTP clients and now everything works. I'm not sure what was going on.

Comment: Incompatibility client/server is possible, but somewhat unlikely if well-known clients were used. It's also possible that something changed in the router's settings, or even if it was just rebooted, or if the server was rebooted and got this time the right IP address.